# .BAT Convert Command using .ICC Color Profile

Tags: batch-file

Using the following code and an .ICM  I am able to convert a single JPG file to sRGB color space:

```
convert C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\color_test\*.jpg \
    -profile "sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm" *.jpg
```

However, when multiple JPG files are in the `color_test` folder they began copying over on a seemingly endless loop. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
FOR %%f IN (C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\color_test\*.jpg) DO (
   convert %%f -profile "sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm" *.jpg 
)
```

Wondering if anyone has any other ideas or can identify why the files are copying over endless times when there is more than one JPG in the `color_test` folder.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot put `*.jpg` in your convert command for each item: that will call convert on each `.jpg` file and store the output in the basename of the `.jpg` file, hopefully not in the same folder.

```
FOR %%f IN (C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop\color_test\*.jpg) DO (
   convert %%f -profile "sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm" %%~nf.jpg
)
```